# Open source project that helps to book printing orders online

Tags: open-source, printing

Is there any open source project/software application (alternative to one by http://www.designnbuy.com/) to meet needs of printing houses wherein users select options such as text, color. font, for a printing item (say business card), get preview of final product, pay online, and printing house ships the final product. The software would run as part of online website (www.portraygraphics.com) designed using Joomla CMS and VirtueMart shopping extension (Joomla itself is not precondition). To start with, one admin will be enough while users will be from world wide web (right now, not started selling online and just to get things right, one order for sample testing would suffice).

Comment: Yor question is very broad, please [edit] it. Where would that software have to run? What are you willing to pay for it? How many items/users does it have to scale to?

Comment: @JanDoggen The software would run as part of online website (www.portraygraphics.com) designed using Joomla CMS and VirtueMart shopping extension (Joomla itself is not precondition). To start with, one admin will be enough while users will be from world wide web.

Comment: Please answer *all* comment questions and [edit] them into your original question as well. Comments can disappear. As for number of users: the number of admins is irrelevant, it's the expected number of site visitors I meant. It's quite different if the software has to handle 10 orders a day or 10000.